# Freeradius sql_counter: share account

Tags: sql, counter, session-timeout, freeradius

I am using freeradius sqlcounter module. I set an account's Max-All-Session to 180 seconds, so the user will be logged out when timeout. When there are two users using this account, I would like to have them logged out if the sum of the two users' access time reach 180 seconds. However, both of them still have 180 seconds. I tried the following config, the `query` will return the account's total access time. The `IFZERO(a,b)` function return `a` if `a == 0` else return `b`. But it didn't work. I also wonder that since the origin `query` always returns `0` before `acctsessiontime` is set, how can this module know the timeout occurs?

```
#/etc/freeradius/sql/mysql/counter.conf
sqlcounter noresetcounter {
    counter-name = Max-All-Session-Time 
            check-name = Max-All-Session 
            sqlmod-inst = sql 
            key = User-Name 
            reset = never 
    #query = "SELECT IFNULL(SUM(AcctSessionTime),0) FROM radacct WHERE UserName='%{%k}'" <= origin one
    query = "SELECT IFZERO(SUM(IFZERO(AcctSessionTime, NOW() - acctstarttime)),0) FROM radacct WHERE UserName='%{%k}'" 
}
```